# Prove $\{0,1\}\cup\{\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{n-1}{n}:n=1,2,\cdots\}$ is compact using the open covering definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I am studying from old exams and have run across this question.  In working with compactness, we only used sequential compactness.  This problem specifically asks for an open covering proof, which I do not know how to work with, as it was not something covered in my class, but is fair game for my comp.  Could someone provide a detailed proof so I can work on understanding the process?

> Prove, using the open covering definition of compactness, that the set $$\{0,1\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} n=1,2,\ldots\right\}\cup\left\{\frac{n-1}{n}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} n=1,2,\ldots\right\}$$ is compact.

Comment: Alyse, if my answer is satsifactory, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark right beneath the voting buttons ([as described here](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)). If it's not satisfactory, could you explain what I should explain in more detail?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Suppose that you have an open covering $\mathscr{U}$ of the set
$$S=\{0,1\}\cup\{\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{n-1}{n}:n=1,2,\cdots\}.$$
Let $U_0,U_1\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open sets in $\mathscr{U}$ that cover the points $0$ and $1$ respectively. Because these sets are open and contain the points $0$ and $1$ respectively, they must also contain points "nearby" to $0$ and $1$. Show that there will only be finitely many elements of $S$ not covered by $U_0$ and $U_1$.